# How to configure CMake to compile MEX-files?

Tags: matlab, cmake, mex

I would like to compile MEX-files (MATLAB executable) in CLion instead of in MATLAB (which gives no help on writing C code). However, MEX-files require the #include mex.h(pp), which is not available on normal C++. Moreover, the format, which does not have a `main` function, is different.

I am using MATLAB R2018b and hoping to use C++11 using [the new C++ API for MEX-files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/cpp-mex-api.html). However, I would be able to use the old API as well.

I have tried looking at [CMake's FindMatlab module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindMatlab.html) and in several other locations. However, most other guides are out of date and even their reference links do not connect to their original pages.

I am an absolute newbie at CMake and I don't know where to begin.

I am currently unable to use `#include "mex.h"`, `#include "mex.hpp"`, `#include "mexAdapter.hpp"` etc. I am also unable to compile a function without a `main` function.

Many thanks in advance for anyone who can help by uploading or describing the  `CMakeLists.txt` file that would be necessary.

Comment: I do not know how CLion works, but can you not create a "myCompile" keyword that would call the MATLAB compiler? I am not sure if you can compile from outside it.

Comment: You may start with command [matlab_add_mex](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindMatlab.html#command:matlab_add_mex). Before using it, you need to call `find_package(Matlab)`. Usage of this command is very similar to "standard" `add_executable` or `add_library`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile a MEX-file, your CMake file should contain:

```
find_package(Matlab)
matlab_add_mex(NAME mex_file_name SRC source_file.cpp)
```

`mex_file_name` is the name of the target, the extension is added automatically. This is a normal target, you can use `set_target_properties`, `target_compile_definitions`, etc. on that target.

If your MEX-file needs to link to a library, add `LINK_TO library` at the end of the `matlab_add_mex` command.

Regarding using the new C++ API: I don't remember if it is necessary to add the `R2018a` flag to the `matlab_add_mex` call. This flag is necessary when using the new C API (complex interleaved) as opposed to the old C API (separate complex). I think it is not necessary for the C++ API, but if things don't compile, add this flag to see if it helps.

Comment: However, I have now found errors such as undefined reference to `mxGetSingles_800' popping up all over the place. I have tried including matrix.h with #include "matrix.h" at the top but it still does not work.

Comment: @veritas9872: please ask a new question for that, including a [mre]. It is impossible for me to know what is wrong from the short description in your comment.

Comment: I had difficulty finding MATLAB(64 bit) on my windows. Apparently the problem seems to be the default platform is set to x86.  Adding  this line to my CMakeLists.txt `set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)` or passing the same definition while configuring solved it.